# Is it possible to access the full profile picture in a custom Apex class without a callout?

Tags: apex, profile

Haven't been able to find anything useful online about this yet... I'm looking to have my app call my existing custom Apex and get the profile picture from that class. I do not want to get the picture by having the app make a separate call to the Chatter API. I want to get the image from my custom Apex class. Is there some simple SOQL I can use to get the full profile picture into my Apex class? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From poking at the schema it seems like you can query the table `UserProfile`. In there there's 2 fields you can use, FullPhotoUrl or SmallPhotoUrl

```
Select SmallPhotoUrl, FullPhotoUrl From UserProfile Where Id = '<insert userId>'
```

After some more quick research this seems to be an Sobject / Table that's not currently accessable called `Photo`. You can test this by using developer console or eclipse and using this piece of code:

`System.debug(System.LoggingLevel.ERROR, Id.valueOf('729J00000004Q8s').getSObjectType());`

The way I got my Id was by copying the photo file URL and copying the Id portion of that url: `https://c.cs10.content.force.com/profilephoto/729J00000004Q8s/F`

List provided may be out of date. [Source from 2011](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html)

> **Key Prefix => Object Type**
>
> 000 => Empty Key
>
> 001 => Account
>
> 002 => Note
>
> 003 => Contact
>
> 005 => User
>
> 006 => Opportunity
>
> 007 => Activity
>
> 008 => OpportunityHistory
>
> 00B => ListView / View
>
> 00D => Organization
>
> 00E => UserRole
>
> 00G => Group
>
> 00I => Partner
>
> Als =>o OpportunityPartner, which "is automatically created when a Partner object is created for a partner relationship between an account and an opportunity"
>
> 00J => OpportunityCompetitor
>
> 00K => OpportunityContactRole
>
> 00N => CustomFieldDefinition - Setup > Create > Objects > [Your Object] > [Your Field]
>
> CF0 =>0N   Custom Field Id using in the query string. Note the keyprefix isn't actually CF0. In this case "CF" has been appended to the "00N" of the Custom Field Definition.
>
> 00O => Report
>
> 00P => Attachment
>
> 00Q => Lead
>
> 00S => ImportQueue
>
> 00T => Task
>
> 00U => Event
>
> 00X => EmailTemplate
>
> 00Y => EmailTemp
>
> 00a => CaseComment or IdeaComment
>
> Use => caution as there are at least two object types exposed via the partner API with the same keyPrefix!
>
> 00a => IdeaComment or CaseComment
>
> Use => caution as there are at least two object types exposed via the partner API with the same keyPrefix!
>
> 00b => WebLink - Custom Button or Link
>
> 00c => Training
>
> 00e => Profile
>
> 00h => Layout - Page Layout
>
> 00i => Pricebook
>
> 00j => Product
>
> 00k => OpportunityLineItem
>
> 00l => Folder
>
> 00o => OpportunityLineItemSchedule
>
> Rep =>resents information about the quantity, revenue distribution, and delivery dates for a particular OpportunityLineItem.
>
> Pro =>ducts, Price Books, and Schedules Overview
>
> 00p => UserTeamMember
>
> 00q => OpportunityTeamMember - "This object is available only in organizations that have enabled team selling."
>
> 00r => AccountShare
>
> 00s => AccountOwnerSharingRule
>
> 00t => OpportunityShare
>
> 00u => OpportunityOwnerSharingRule
>
> 00v => CampaignMember
>
> 010 => CaseSolution
>
> 011 => GroupMember
>
> 012 => RecordType
>
> 013 => RecordTypePicklist
>
> 014 => ProfileRecordType
>
> 015 => Document
>
> 016 => BrandTemplate (Letterhead)
>
> 017 => Entity History
>
> 018 => EmailStatus
>
> 019 => BusinessProcess
>
> 01A => BusinessProcessPicklist
>
> 01B => LayoutSection
>
> 01C => LayoutItem
>
> 01D => UserAccountTeamMember
>
> 01G => ProfileLayout
>
> 01H => MailmergeTemplate
>
> 01I => Custom Object
>
> 01J => PicklistMaster
>
> 01N => Scontrol
>
> 01P => ProfileTabConfiguration
>
> 01Q => WorkflowRule - AssignmentRule
>
> 01R => RuleFilter
>
> 01S => RuleFilterItem
>
> 01T => RuleFilterAction
>
> 01U => ActionAssignEscalate
>
> 01V => ActionTask
>
> 01W => ActionEmail
>
> 01X => ActionEmailRecipient
>
> 01Y => CampaignMemberStatus
>
> 01Z => Dashboard
>
> 01a => DashboardComponent
>
> 01b => ListViewCriterion
>
> 01c => ListViewDisplayColumn
>
> 01e => PicklistSet
>
> 01h => Translation
>
> 01j => LocalizedValue
>
> 01k => FieldPermissions
>
> 01l => ActionResponse
>
> 01m => BusinessHours
>
> 01n => CaseShare
>
> 01o => LeadShare
>
> 01p => ApexClass
>
> 01q => ApexTrigger
>
> 01r => CustomTabDefinition - Visualforce Tab
>
> 01s => Pricebook2
>
> 01t => Product2
>
> 01u => PricebookEntry
>
> 01v => PricebookShare
>
> 01w => OpportunityUpdateReminder
>
> 01y => CaseOwnerSharingRule
>
> 01z => CaseEscalation
>
> 020 => EventAttendee
>
> 022 => FiscalYearSettings
>
> 023 => Calendar
>
> 024 => CalendarShare
>
> 025 => ListLayoutItem
>
> 026 => Period
>
> 02A => LeadOwnerSharingRule
>
> 02B => LabelDefinition
>
> 02C => LabelData
>
> 02D => CaseHistory2
>
> 02F => CustomFieldMap
>
> 02T => CustomPage
>
> 02U => CustomPageItem
>
> 02V => PageComponent
>
> 02X => CustomPageProfile
>
> 02Y => UserComponentData
>
> 02Z => AccountContactRole
>
> 02a => ContractContactRole
>
> 02b => ComponentResourceLink
>
> 02c => Sharing Rule
>
> 02f => DelegateGroup
>
> 02g => DelegateGroupMember
>
> 02h => DelegateGroupGrant
>
> 02i => Asset
>
> 02k => ListLayout
>
> 02m => CustomIndex
>
> 02n => CategoryNode
>
> 02o => CategoryData
>
> 02p => DivTransferEvent
>
> 02q => LayoutItemColumn
>
> 02r => OpportunityAlert
>
> 02t => EmailRoutingAddress
>
> 02u => TabSet - AKA. Apps
>
> 02v => TabSetMember
>
> 02w => LoginIpRange
>
> 02x => LoginHours
>
> 02y => ReportAggregate
>
> 02z => ReportColorRange
>
> 033 => AllPackage - Package being built in the developer org
>
> 034 => PackageMember
>
> 035 => SelfServiceUser
>
> 036 => JobQueue
>
> 037 => ReportColumn
>
> 038 => ReportFilterItem
>
> 039 => ReportBreak
>
> 03D => ContactOwnerSharingRule
>
> 03G => AccountCriteriaSharingRule
>
> 03H => ContactCriteriaSharingRule
>
> 03I => CaseCriteriaSharingRule
>
> 03J => ChatterMessage
>
> 03K => ChatterMessageThread
>
> 03M => ChatterConversation
>
> 03N => ChatterConversationMember
>
> 03a => DependentPicklist
>
> 03c => LayoutRightPanel
>
> 03d => ValidationFormula - Validation Rule
>
> 03e => CustomSetupDefinition
>
> 03f => CustomSetup
>
> 03g => QueueSobject
>
> 03i => ConsoleConfig
>
> 03j => CaseContactRole
>
> 03k => ConsoleConfigItem
>
> 03n => ApexClassIdentifier
>
> 03q => ApexClassIdentifierRelationship
>
> 03s => ContactShare
>
> 03u => UserPreference
>
> 040 => ReportParam
>
> 043 => OutboundField
>
> 044 => ExternalizedReference
>
> 045 => PartnerNetworkSetup
>
> 04Y => ActionFieldUpdate - Field Update
>
> 04Z => EntityLock
>
> 04a => ProcessDefinition
>
> 04b => ProcessNode
>
> 04c => ProcessTransition
>
> 04d => ProcessTransitionCondition
>
> 04e => ProcessActionItem
>
> 04f => ProcessWorkitemProperties
>
> 04g => ProcessInstance
>
> 04h => ProcessInstanceStep
>
> 04i => ProcessInstanceWorkitem
>
> 04j => ProcessAllowedSubmitter
>
> 04k => ActionOutboundMessage - Outbound Message Id
>
> 04l => OutboundMessage - Outbound Notification Id
>
> 04m => AdditionalNumber
>
> 04n => SoftphoneLayout
>
> 04o => SoftphoneLayoutSection
>
> 04p => SoftphoneLayoutItem
>
> 04q => SoftphoneLayoutInfoField
>
> 04r => SoftphoneLayoutCallType
>
> 04s => AsyncRequest - AsyncResult, DeployResult
>
> 04t => AllPackageVersion - Install Package
>
> 04u => ActionOverride
>
> 04v => CallCenter
>
> 04x => PackageExtension
>
> 04z => LayoutItemActionRef
>
> 04V => PartnerNetworkRecordConnection
>
> 04P => PartnerNetworkConnection
>
> 050 => PackageLicense
>
> 051 => UserPackageLicense
>
> 052 => SfdcOutboundMessage
>
> 053 => WorkflowTimeTrigger
>
> 054 => WorkflowTimeAction
>
> 055 => WorkflowTimeQueue
>
> 056 => ContentTagName
>
> 057 => ContentDocumentSubscription
>
> 058 => ContentWorkspace
>
> 059 => ContentWorkspaceDoc
>
> 05A => ContentWorkspaceMembership
>
> 05B => CampaignCriteriaSharingRule
>
> 05C => ContentVersionComment
>
> 05G => IpWhitelist
>
> 05I => CampaignSharingRuleFilterItem
>
> 05J => ContentVersionRating
>
> 05K => ContentVersionRenditionContent
>
> 05L => DBCThumbnailFilter
>
> 05N => ContentVersionTagName
>
> 05P => ContentWorkspacePermission
>
> 05Q => ContentTagSubscription
>
> 05R => ContentWorkspaceSubscription
>
> 05S => ContentUserSubscription
>
> 05T => ContentContent
>
> 05U => EntityFeedLayout
>
> 05V => ContentNotification
>
> 05W => ContentNotificationParam
>
> 05X => DocumentAttachmentMap
>
> 05Z => ContentWorkspaceRecentEvent
>
> 05t => CustomEntityTranslation
>
> 060 => Portal
>
> 061 => PortalAccount
>
> 062 => PortalStyleConfig
>
> 063 => MobileConfig
>
> 064 => QuerySet
>
> 065 => QuerySetItem
>
> 066 => ApexPage
>
> 067 => PortalMember
>
> 068 => ContentVersion
>
> 069 => ContentDocument
>
> 06A => ContentDocumentLink
>
> 06B => ContentWorkspaceAllowedRecType
>
> 06G => CustomConsoleComponent
>
> 06N => ApplicationDependency
>
> 06O => ServiceDeskAttributes
>
> 06P => Application - Connected App
>
> 070 => CustomReportType
>
> 071 => CrtObject
>
> 072 => CrtColumn - Related to reports in some way.
>
> 073 => CrtLayoutSection
>
> 076 => RateLimitingNotification
>
> 078 => ApiUsage
>
> 079 => MobileMarkedRecord
>
> 07A => MassMail
>
> 07D => FeedPostTemplate
>
> 07E => Sandbox
>
> 07F => FeedFavorite
>
> 07G => SummaryRecalcQueue
>
> 07J => ComponentObjectDependency
>
> 07K => ComponentFeatureDependency
>
> 07L => ApexLog
>
> 07M => ApexTestResult
>
> 07O => Canvas
>
> 07P => EntitySizeJob
>
> 07R => DataCategoryMapping
>
> 07T => AuthConfig
>
> 07U => AuthConfigProviders
>
> 07V => ActionSend
>
> 07Y => BatchOrgSizeJob
>
> 07Z => EntityDataSize
>
> 07e => FeedPostTemplateItem
>
> 07n => ApexExecutionOverlayResult
>
> 080 => PacCrudPermission
>
> 081 => StaticResource
>
> 082 => UninstallExport - Data from Uninstalled Packages? A zip containing CSVs.
>
> 083 => Vote
>
> 084 => VoteConfig
>
> 085 => VoteStats
>
> 086 => MobileDevice
>
> 087 => Idea
>
> 08E => AddressCountry
>
> 08F => AddressState
>
> 08a => CronJobDetail
>
> 08d => CampaignOwnerSharingRule
>
> 08e => CronTrigger
>
> 08g => CronFiredTrigger
>
> 08s => CampaignShare
>
> 090 => MobileExcludedField
>
> 091 => EmailServicesFunction
>
> 092 => Weekly Data Export
>
> 093 => EmailServicesAddress
>
> 094 => MobileView
>
> 095 => MobileViewSortColumn
>
> 096 => MobileViewDisplayColumn
>
> 097 => MobileViewFilter
>
> 099 => ApexComponent
>
> 09A => FeedPollChoice
>
> 09B => FeedPollVote
>
> 09D => QuickActionDefinition
>
> 09F => DatacloudPurchaseUsage
>
> 09H => ConnectedApplication2
>
> 09I => QuickActionListItem
>
> 09J => QuickActionList
>
> 09S => AsyncRequestFFX
>
> 09T => AsyncRequestFFXResult
>
> 09U => DomainCookieStore
>
> 09V => DashboardStickyFilter
>
> 09a => Community
>
> 0A0 => ReportJob
>
> 0A1 => ReportJobFieldMap
>
> 0A2 => DevelopmentPackageVersion - Change Set
>
> 0A3 => InstalledPackageVersion - Installed Package
>
> 0A4 => ProcessTransitionApprover
>
> 0A5 => AllManagedPackageMember
>
> 0A7 => CustomShareRowCause
>
> 0A8 => ReportJobRun
>
> 0A9 => ReportJobRunError
>
> 0AB => ProfilePortalDelegate
>
> 0AD => PackageEvent
>
> 0AH => CompactLayout
>
> 0AI => FirehoseCheckpoint
>
> 0AL => ExternalSocialAccount
>
> 0AM => CompactLayoutItem
>
> 0AN => CompactLayoutMapping
>
> 0AT => EventLogFile
>
> 0AU => AuthSecurityLevel
>
> 0AW => CanvasFeedItem
>
> 0AX => ConsolePersonalization
>
> 0AZ => ActionApex
>
> 0Af => DeployRequest
>
> 0Ai => DeployMessage
>
> 0Aj => AsyncApiTransformationSpec
>
> 0Ak => AuthSession
>
> 0Al => DeployTestResult
>
> 0B0 => MobileEntitySetting
>
> 0B1 => MessageIdentifier
>
> 0B2 => PortalLanguageConfig
>
> 0B3 => PortalLanguageTabConfig
>
> 0B9 => MobileTab
>
> 0BA => CustomDataType
>
> 0BB => CustomDataTypeComponent
>
> 0BC => CustomFieldDataColumn
>
> 0BE => FileFieldData
>
> 0BF => ComponentAppVersion
>
> 0BG => CampaignInfluenceAdjustment
>
> 0BH => AllManagedClassRelationship
>
> 0BI => ContentVersionMap
>
> 0BJ => ActionAssignTeam
>
> 0BL => PackageIdMapping
>
> 0BM => Connection - Salesforce to Salesforce
>
> 0BR => LogSearchResult
>
> 0BV => OpportunityCriteriaSharingRule
>
> 0BW => MobilePushDevice
>
> 0BX => HistoricalEntityConfig
>
> 0BY => MqSlaRequest
>
> 0BZ => EmailBrand
>
> 0Ba => LoginBrandAsset
>
> 0Bb => LoginBrand
>
> 0Bc => MqSlaJob
>
> 0Bd => HistoricalFieldConfig
>
> 0Be => HistoricalTransactionPrefix
>
> 0Bf => HistoricalStaging
>
> 0Bi => HistoricalSelectorValue
>
> 0Bk => HistoricalSelector
>
> 0Bl => BlacklistedConsumer
>
> 0C0 => Holiday
>
> 0C2 => MobileSession
>
> 0C8 => LongJob
>
> 0CC => SiteChangelistComponent
>
> 0CF => ChatterNowUserFavorites
>
> 0CI => EntityImplements
>
> 0CJ => FieldImplements
>
> 0CL => SiteChangelist
>
> 0CS => ChatterNowUserSettings
>
> 0Ci => AppManifest
>
> 0D1 => DataCategoryGroup
>
> 0D2 => OrgWideEmailAddress
>
> 0D3 => OrgEmailAddressSecurity
>
> 0D4 => LeadCriteriaSharingRule
>
> 0D5 => FeedItem or NewsFeed or UserProfileFeed
>
> Use => caution as there are at least three object types exposed via the partner API with the same keyPrefix!
>
> 0D6 => FeedTrackedChange
>
> 0D7 => FeedComment
>
> 0D8 => AllManagedMemberOption
>
> 0D9 => LeadSharingRuleFilterItem
>
> 0DA => EntityCategoryGroup
>
> 0DC => ProcessTransitionAction
>
> 0DD => SynonymGroup
>
> 0DE => Synonym
>
> 0DF => VersionSet
>
> 0DG => NamedFilter
>
> 0DH => FieldAttributes
>
> 0DM => Site
>
> 0DN => SitePageOverride
>
> 0DR => AndroidPushApplicationSetup
>
> 0DS => AppMenuItem
>
> 0DT => IdeaReputationLevel
>
> 0DU => LimitUsageHistory
>
> 0DV => PushUpgradeRequest
>
> 0DX => PushUpgradeJob
>
> 0DY => PushUpgradeJobError
>
> 0Db => ForecastingType
>
> 0Df => InstanceSizeJob
>
> 0E0 => EmailSyncConfig
>
> 0E1 => EmailSyncEntitySetting
>
> 0E2 => EmailSyncFieldMapping
>
> 0E3 => EmailSyncValueMapping
>
> 0E4 => EmailConfigEntitySetting
>
> 0E5 => EmailUserEntitySetting
>
> 0E6 => EmailSyncAdvancedSetting
>
> 0E8 => EntitySubscription
>
> 0EA => PackageVersionPatchOrg
>
> 0EB => Renderer
>
> 0EG => ReportChart
>
> 0EH => SummaryLayout
>
> 0EI => SummaryLayoutItem
>
> 0EJ => SummaryLayoutSliceInfo
>
> 0EM => ContentReference - Appears next to refid query string parameter when pulling images. See rtaimage servlet parameters…what does the refid refer to?
>
> 0EO => PicklistItemProperty
>
> 0EP => Inbound Change Set?
>
> 0EQ => CategoryJobTask
>
> 0ER => RichTextAreaFieldData
>
> 0EV => AllInstalledPackageVersion
>
> 0Eb => ModuleDependency
>
> 0Ee => HistoricalDataFilter
>
> 0Ef => HistoricalDataFilterItem
>
> 0Eg => GlobalDbKey
>
> 0F0 => EmailTempAttachmentMap
>
> 0F3 => ReportBlock
>
> 0F5 => PhotoItem
>
> 0F7 => FeedPost
>
> 0F8 => SoftphoneScreenPopOption
>
> 0F9 => CollaborationGroup
>
> 0FA => CsnDomain
>
> 0FB => CollaborationGroupMember
>
> 0FG => MobilePushServiceDevice
>
> 0FH => LinkReference
>
> 0FM => FeedMapping
>
> 0FO => OrgSizeJob
>
> 0FP => ReportRunTracker
>
> 0FQ => TrialMaster
>
> 0FR => PackageOperationError
>
> 0FT => TopicAssignment
>
> 0Fa => ContextFieldAttributes
>
> 0G1 => FeedFieldHistory
>
> 0G8 => ReportBucketField
>
> 0G9 => AccountSharingRuleFilterItem
>
> 0GC => EmailDisclaimer
>
> 0GD => ReportBucketFieldValue
>
> 0GE => ReportBucketFieldSourceValue
>
> 0GH => SchemaBuilderLayout
>
> 0GI => SchemaBuilderLayoutItem
>
> 0GJ => ApplePushApplicationSetup
>
> 0H0 => SiteRedirectMapping
>
> 0H1 => CollaborationInvitation
>
> 0H4 => ConnectedApplication
>
> 0H7 => PackageSupportAccess
>
> 0HF => PublishEvent
>
> 0HG => EntitySharingModel
>
> 0HI => ReportBlockAggregate
>
> 0HN => TwoFactorInfo
>
> 0HO => MobilePushSetupRegistry
>
> 0HR => MetricsTransmissionHistory
>
> 0Hi => AppIpRange
>
> 0Hj => AppManifestVersion
>
> 0Hk => ConnectivityDevConfig
>
> 0Hl => ConnectivityAttributes
>
> 0I0 => FeedLike
>
> 0I2 => SiteAsset
>
> 0I3 => SiteComponent
>
> 0I4 => Domain
>
> 0I5 => CollaborationGroupMemberRequest
>
> 0I6 => OpportunitySharingRuleFilterItem
>
> 0I7 => CaseSharingRuleFilterItem
>
> 0I8 => ContactSharingRuleFilterItem
>
> 0I9 => ReportObjectFilterItem
>
> 0IA => KnowledgeLanguageConfig
>
> 0IB => DashboardFilter
>
> 0IC => DashboardFilterItem
>
> 0ID => DashboardFilterRepCol
>
> 0IF => PushTopic
>
> 0II => FeedCrossReference
>
> 0IO => BrandingValue
>
> 0IS => ApexComponentAttribute
>
> 0IV => LogSearch
>
> 0IX => FieldSet
>
> 0IY => FieldSetItem
>
> 0Ih => ServiceDeskComponent
>
> 0Ii => PushProfileMapping
>
> 0Ij => PushIntent
>
> 0Ik => Module
>
> 0In => PhoenixDataSync
>
> 0Io => RawEmail
>
> 0J0 => SetupEntityAccess
>
> 0J2 => Personalization
>
> 0J4 => SPSamlAttributes
>
> 0J5 => PredictiveModel
>
> 0J8 => ServiceDeskHotkey
>
> 0JS => JigsawSavedSearch
>
> 0Jf => DomainSite
>
> 0K0 => ActionKnowledgeSubmit
>
> 0K2 => ActionChatterPost
>
> 0K3 => ActionChatterPostRecipient
>
> 0LD => RecalcCampaignStats
>
> 0LG => ReportInstance
>
> 0LN => StorageSizeJob
>
> 0M1 => SocialUserAuth
>
> 0ME => SessionLevelPolicy
>
> 0MF => SynonymDictionary
>
> 0MJ => SystemStreamingChannel
>
> 0O0 => XinstanceInfo
>
> 0P0 => FlowVariableAssignment
>
> 0P1 => Certificate
>
> 0P2 => CertificateIp
>
> 0PF => ParallelJobItemData
>
> 0PL => PermissionSetLicense
>
> 0PQ => ProcessTimeQueue
>
> 0PS => PermissionSet - Permission set metadata
>
> 0Pa => PermissionSetAssignment
>
> 0Q0 => Quote
>
> 0Qc => ActionQuickCreate
>
> 0RA => ActivityRelation
>
> 0RE => EventRelation
>
> 0RT => TaskRelation
>
> 0SO => AuthProvider
>
> 0TI => TopicIndex
>
> 0TO => Topic
>
> 0TY => TopicOntology
>
> 0Tt => TopicTerm
>
> 0XC => ExternalDataSource
>
> 0XU => ExternalDataUserAuth
>
> 0Ya => LoginHistory
>
> 0Ym => SetupAuditTrail
>
> 0Ys => ParallelJobStatus
>
> 0Yu => IdpEventLog
>
> 0Yw => UserLogin
>
> 0ca => ChatterActivity
>
> 0cs => OauthConsumerScope
>
> 0e1 => ProfileClientSettings
>
> 0eb => EntityBlacklist
>
> 0hc => HashtagCount
>
> 0hd => HashtagDefinition
>
> 0ht => Hashtag
>
> 0in => Influence
>
> 0ns => ProcessNodeSecurity
>
> 0rp => RemoteProxy
>
> 0sp => ServiceProvider
>
> 0tR => TopicRecordSetting
>
> 0tS => TopicSuggestionSetting
>
> 0te => TopicUserEvent
>
> 0tg => TopicGroupActivity
>
> 0tr => TrendingTopic
>
> 0ts => ProcessTransitionSecurity
>
> 0tu => TopicUserActivity
>
> 100 => UserLicense
>
> 101 => ExternalString - Custom Label
>
> 102 => FeatureLicense
>
> 10y => TaskRecurrenceException
>
> 10z => EventRecurrenceException
>
> 110 => ObjectPermissions
>
> 111 => EventComments
>
> 112 => ProposedEventTime
>
> 113 => ProposedEventResponse
>
> 11a => DBCThumbnail
>
> 1ci => Integration
>
> 1cl => ChangeList
>
> 1dc => MetadataContainer - from the Tooling AP
>
> 1de => IDEWorkspace
>
> 1do => ApexExecutionOverlayAction
>
> 1dp => IDEPerspective
>
> 1dr => ContainerAsyncRequest - from the Tooling API
>
> 204 => SfdcPartner
>
> 2LA => PermissionSetLicenseAssign
>
> 300 => InteractionDefinition
>
> 301 => InteractionDefinitionVersion
>
> 308 => InteractionCondition
>
> 309 => InteractionOperand
>
> 30A => InteractionAllocator
>
> 30C => InteractionChoice
>
> 30D => InteractionDecision
>
> 30F => InteractionForm
>
> 30L => InteractionConnector
>
> 30Q => InteractionQuestion
>
> 30R => InteractionReference
>
> 30S => InteractionStatement
>
> 30V => InteractionVariable
>
> 30a => InteractionAllocation
>
> 30c => InteractionConstant
>
> 30d => InteractionDataColumn
>
> 30f => InteractionFormula
>
> 30g => InteractionLayoutGroup
>
> 30m => InteractionApexCall
>
> 30r => InteractionResource
>
> 30t => InteractionTodo
>
> 30v => InteractionValueList
>
> 310 => InteractionLayoutDetail
>
> 31A => Subinteraction
>
> 31C => SubinteractionVariableAssignment
>
> 31S => InteractionSwitch
>
> 31V => InteractionFieldValue
>
> 31c => InteractionChoiceLookup
>
> 31d => InteractionDataSource
>
> 31i => InteractionDataInput
>
> 31o => InteractionDataOutput
>
> 31v => InteractionValueListEntry
>
> 3M1 => OrgObjectsMetrics
>
> 3M3 => ChatterMetrics
>
> 3M4 => ChatterOrgWideMetrics
>
> 3M5 => NetworkCustomerLoginMetrics
>
> 3M6 => NetworkPartnerLoginMetrics
>
> 3MA => PermissionSetMetricsByOrg
>
> 3MC => OpportunityMetrics
>
> 3MD => ContentMetrics
>
> 3MF => SharingRowCauseMetrics
>
> 3MG => SharingMetrics
>
> 3MH => IdeaMetrics
>
> 3MI => UserDimMetrics
>
> 3MJ => PermissionSetLicenseMetrics
>
> 400 => ApexClassMember
>
> 401 => ApexTriggerMember
>
> 402 => ApexPageMember
>
> 403 => ApexComponentMember
>
> 4A0 => MetadataCheckout
>
> 4F0 => ApexClassVersion
>
> 4F1 => ApexTriggerVersion
>
> 4F2 => ApexPageVersion
>
> 4F3 => ApexComponentVersion
>
> 500 => Case
>
> 501 => Solution
>
> 5Sp => SegmentSpace
>
> 5CS => Chat Session
>
> 608 => ForecastShare
>
> 6AA => AssociationQueueItem
>
> 6AB => EventAssociationItem
>
> 6AC => MailAssociationItem
>
> 6AD => TaskAssociationItem
>
> 701 => Campaign
>
> 707 => AsyncApexJob
>
> 708 => BatchApexRelationship
>
> 709 => ApexTestQueueItem
>
> 710 => LoginIp
>
> 711 => ApiLoginKey
>
> 712 => LoginIpEmail
>
> 713 => ClientBrowser
>
> 714 => ApexCodeCoverage
>
> 715 => ApexCodeCoverageAggregate
>
> 716 => ApexOrgWideCoverage
>
> 729 => Photo
>
> 737 => FieldHistory
>
> 750 => AsyncApiJob - Bulk Query Job
>
> 751 => AsyncApiBatch - Bulk Query Batch
>
> 752 => AsyncApiQueryResult - Bulk Query Result
>
> 753 => TempStore
>
> 754 => AsyncApiJobOptions
>
> 766 => UiStyleDefinition
>
> 777 => UiStyle
>
> 7tf => TraceFlag
>
> 800 => Contract
>
> 806 => Approval
>
> 80D => OrganizationValue
>
> 888 => OauthConsumer - Remote Access
>
> ka0 => Article - Knowledge Article
>
> X00 => Found in the PermissionSet Name column where the ProfileId is also defined. It matches the ProfileId with the exception of the key prefix.

Comment: Yes, but then I have to make a callout to the URL, I'm trying to avoid that. I just want to get the raw picture data.

Comment: Check out my answer

Comment: @DoubleA If the table is not accessible from Apex how does this help?

Comment: It's letting Brad know as far as APEX, this isn't possible since the table he wanted to look at for the blob information isn't accessible in the way he wanted without making some sort of outbound call.

Comment: +1 for the research, thank you, interesting about the prefixes, I didn't know that.

Comment: @DoubleA I see; might come over clearer using the newspaper style of starting with the headline of "No" and then going into the detail...