# Capturing Date when Case Owner is changed from Queue to User

Tags: visual-workflow, case

I'm trying to create a Flow to capture the date/time when case owner is changed from queue to user.
I been trying different variations to capture the date but it's never a sure-fire thing...

Right now, I separated it into 2 Flows - one when case is created and other one when it's updated.
The first one is pretty straightforward and I haven't had any trouble capturing the data but it's the latter one that's giving me trouble.

We have 2 scenarios --

1. Case is owned by Queue and User accepts the case
   [image]
2. Case is owner by Queue and then transfer to another Queue and then User accepts the case (troublemaker)
   [image]

This is the current Flow I have -
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm wondering if there's a better way to make it so that it's sure thing and doesn't skip a case when Case Owner is change to an User.

Any advice would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Pro tip - don't use hardcoded queueIds; instead, query for the queues by developerName to decide if they qualify

Comment: hey @cropredy thanks for the advice. how should i go about doing that. do i just reference {!$Record.Owner:Group.DeveloperName} equal to Triage Email and use the Default Outcome to stamp the date?

Comment: Give it a whirl

Comment: no luck. it skips when case goes from triage email to user add and then to user...i'm not sure what's going on...i'm gonna give joana's method. cross fingers.

Comment: It was actually records that was touched by Omni-Channel and those doesn't trigger any automations. Workaround would be building on AgentWork object and populating the date field when AgentWork record gets created.

Comment: You should add what you discovered as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Automated Process such as Process Builder/ Workflow/ Flows won't get trigger if records are touched by Omni-Channel.

In my scenario, cases were getting routing via Omni-Channel to users and when they accepts the case, it doesn't trigger any processes I have built.

Workaround is to create a process on AgentWork object to trigger the Flow. When AgentWork record is created, that's when the case is assigned to the user and triggers the flow.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to capture date/time when case owner is changed from Queue -> User, why not leverage the record identifier prefixes?

- User records always start with 005
- Queues (or Groups) always start with 00G

See reference [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30463/is-it-possible-to-access-the-full-profile-picture-in-a-custom-apex-class-without).

#1. START: evalute IsChanged for the OwnerId
[image]

#2. DECISION: evaluate if previous owner was Queue (Group) and new owner is user
[image]

Comment: i'll give that a shot. should i keep it as fast field update for the start? it always skips when case goes from triage email to user add then to the user for some reason...

Comment: It was actually records that was touched by Omni-Channel and those doesn't trigger any automations. Workaround would be building on AgentWork object and populating the date field when AgentWork record gets created.